# How to show SQL result as percentage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to pull a report from the database and currently there is a column which displays the scores. How can I convert the score into % number?

In theory it would be easy but as I'm not an SQL export it's not.

I tried

```
select [userid], [QuestionsTotal] / 100 * [QuestionsCorrect] as 'score'
   FROM myTable
```

and I also tried

```
select [userid], [QuestionsTotal] / [QuestionsCorrect] * 100.0  as 'score'
FROM myTable
```

Could anyone give me some hints on how I can solve my problem?

Comment: (questionsCorrect/questionsTotal)*100 ?

Comment: This is not a SQL issue you're doing your division wrong, it should be QuestionsCorrect / QuestionsTotal * 100

Comment: Please add some (example) data to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your Correct and Total are INTs.  Notice the *100.0  -- The .0 is important to convert at least one of your factors to something other than INT.

```
select [userid]
     , ([QuestionsCorrect]*100.0) / [QuestionsTotal]  as 'score'
   FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve this result that I used (can be used for SUM,COUNT, AVG..):

```
 Select Category as 'Category', COUNT(Category) as 'Count' , 

    CAST(COUNT(Category) as DECIMAL(10,4)) /  SUM(COUNT(Category) ) OVER () * 100 '% Allocation'

    from Category
```